# Showing keyboard on SKScene and performing action on a sprite node based on key tapped

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I am trying to learn SpriteKit and play with some simple sample apps.

Currently I am trying to achieve below things:

1. Show keyboard over SKScene
2. If user taps 'A', perform some action on a sprite node, if user taps 'B' perform some other action on other sprite nodes

To achieve 1st requirement I tried below steps:

**Step 1:** In GameViewController.swift, added a reference to the view.

```
var keyView: KeyboardDummyView?
```

**Step 2:** In viewDidLoad(), created the view, assigned it to the ivar, and added it to the controller's view. Also assigned "self" to a backreference ivar in GameScene.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // So scene can forward touch event back here.
        scene.gvc = self

        // Other config

        keyView = KeyboardDummyView(frame: self.view.frame)
         self.view.addSubview(keyView!)
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Added a function to handle a tap/touch.

```
func handleTap() {
    // Show the keyboard
    keyView!.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

**Step 4:** In GameScene.swift added the reference to the controller.

```
var gvc: GameViewController?
```

**Step 5:** In touchesBegan handled tap.

```
gvc!.handleTap()
```

But for some reasons it is not showing the keyboard when screen is tapped :(

Here is the code base: [KeyboardOverSKScene](https://github.com/Daemon-Devarshi/KeyboardOverSKScene)

Please suggest if I am doing any thing wrong?

***Note:*** I am trying this in Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: "not working as expected" is not a problem description, please clarify.